# session being unexpectedly destroyed

Tags: php, session, payment-gateway

I have built an e-comm site that stores session variables for various uses, though the session is being unexpectedly destroyed and i cant work out why.

The session is being destroyed when a user is redirected back to my site after completing a PayPal payment or a SecurePay payment, but it only happens once, only the first time the completes a payment each day, if that makes sense. For example, if the same user comes an hour later and purchases something else, when the user is redirected back to my website after completeing the second payment the session is not destroyed, it works as intended.

Even when i am testing on non-live payment gateway such as sandbox it will destroy the session when redirecting back to my website, but only the first time, as soon and i make another test payment it will work fine, until the next morning when i try again and it will destroy the session again, etc.

I also now have a ssl certificate for my website as i had read that it could have been destroyed because it's redirecting from a HTTPS:// to a HTTP:// . But having the SSL makes no difference, the session is still being destroyed.

There is also absolutley no code to destroy the session on either of my PayPal or securepay returnURLS

Does anyone know why it might be causing this?

Comment: Is the originating and returning domain the same? A common mistake can be a leading "www."

Comment: Yeah, they are both the same. If they were different, wouldn't that mean the session would be destroyed everytime the user is redirected back to the site?

Comment: Depends on your testing. Imagine start point www.example.com (session a), redirects to paypal, which returns to example.com (no wwww. / session b). Then on second purchase the use is still at example.com (session b) from first purchase and gets redirected back to example.com (still session b).

Comment: Far as I know, sessions don't work on cross-domain.

Comment: @Fred Why doesn't it do it everytime the user is redirected, not only just once?

Comment: @clemens321 Interesting point. I will double check to make sure it is definitley all the same, though im 99% sure it is.

Comment: hard to say. Could be session life on your server's config, could be something with your code.

Comment: Sessions don't work cross-domain, but when you come back to your originating domain your session should be still there (respecting lifetime etc., but a payment shouldn't take THAT long). Same rules as for ordinary cookies apply.